# How do I solve this inequality using these statements?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Here is problem 16 from section 1.1 in the book "Calculus A Rigorous First Course", by Daniel J. Velleman:

\begin{align}
\text{Solve} \; 2|x|-3 \ge |x-1| \; \text{by using theorem 1.1.2.}
\end{align}
Where theorem 1.1.2 states:

*For any numbers $x$ and $y$, the following statements are true:*

1. $|x|<y$ iff $-y<x<y$
2. $|x|\le y$ iff $-y\le x \le y$
3. $|x| \ge y$ iff either $x\le -y$ or $x\ge y$
4. $|x| > y$ iff either $x<-y$ or $x > y$

**Edit**: Here is what I've tried so far:

By the second statement, we get:

\begin{align}
-2|x|+4\le x\le2|x|-2
\end{align}

We can split into two inequalities, and arrive at the following;

\begin{align}
-\frac{x-4}{2}\ge|x| \; \; \text{and} \; \; \frac{x+2}{2}\le|x|
\end{align}

Applying the second statement to the left inequality and the third statement to the other inequality gives us

\begin{align}
\frac{x-4}{2}\le x \le \frac{4-x}{2} \; \; \text{and} \; \; x \le -\frac{x+2}{2} \; \text{or} \; x \ge \frac{x+2}{2}
\end{align}

By this, our solution set is defined as: $\{ x : \text{either}\; -4 \le x \le \frac{4}{3} \; \text{or} \; x\ge 2 \} $. But, this is not the result I arrived at when reasoning by cases.

**Case #1:** Consider whenever $x<0$, then $-2x-3 \ge 1-x$, therefore true if $x\le-4$.

**Case #2:** Consider whenever $0\le x<1$, then $2x-3\ge x-1$, therefore $x\ge \frac{4}{3}$, but since this exceeds our initial condition, the interval $[0,1)$ is not included in our solution set.

**Case #3:** Consider whenever $x \ge 0$, then $2x-3 \ge x-1$, therefore true if $x \ge 2$.

By this, our solution set is defined as: $\{ x : \text{either}\; x \le -4 \; \text{or} \; x\ge 2 \} $.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Note the close-voter: you clearly haven’t read the question....

Comment: I haven't checked this in detail but isn't there a mistake at the beginning of your edit? I get by the second statement$-2|x|+4\le x\le2|x|-2$.

Comment: oh let me fix that

Comment: When you divide both sides of an inequality by -2, you have to reverse the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Also, when you split into two inequalities, you separated them by a comma.  I'm not sure what that comma means.  It would be clearer to write "and" rather than a comma, since you need both inequalities to be true.

Comment: Thanks! Are you Daniel J. Velleman? Author of the book?

Comment: Yes, that's me.

Comment: When you split the inequality into two inequalities (now connected by "and"), the inequality sign is still backwards in the first one, because you have to reverse the direction of an inequality when you multiply or divide both sides by a negative number.